# update query maysql from second table

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have 2 table and need to update one column of 1st table

I have tried with this

```
update user_details as ud set ud.corporationName =
select cop.corporationName FROM corporation as cop where cop.id = ud.corporation_id
```

help me to fix it .
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an update based on inner  join

```
update user_details  ud 
INNER JOIN corporation cop ON  cop.id = ud.corporation_id
set ud.corporationName =  cop.corporationName
```